# 403 permission denied for google drive api PHP

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm having trouble authenticating both the calendar API and google drive API. I had calendar API working, and I wanted to add the google drive attachment functionality to it, but can't get it to work. It's giving me the this error
An error occurred: Error calling GET     https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files: (403) Insufficient Permission

here is my code:

```
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
$client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");

$googleService = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);*/
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY)
));

// Setup the Google Calendar class
$googleClient = new Google_Client();
$googleClient->setApplicationName('test');
$googleClient->setScopes(SCOPES);
$googleClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$googleClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/Calendar");
$googleClient->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$googleService = new Google_Service_Calendar($googleClient);
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($googleClient);
```

I have no idea why calendar works and google drive doesn't, and I'm pretty sure that the authentication in CLIENT_SECRET_PATH works for google drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.. I authenticated a google Service before that without the google drive api scope and apparently the authentication doesn't overwrite.